# Upgrade process for Liferay DXP

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have a portlet bundle as a war in Liferay 6.2. We are planning to convert it into module as per the Liferay 7. So we have the change of Portlet name and hence Id.

Now we would like to run the upgrade process which will take care below scenarios

- Updating Portlet Preferences with new Portlet Id
- Updating Layouts to consider new Portlet Id
- Updating ResourceAction table to consider new Portlet Id

I have undergone few dev.liferay.com but couldn't fine proper guide to do the same. I followed 6.2 approach by creating the Upgrade class by extending UpgradeProcess class and then overriding the threshold values. However, it doesn't work for me.

Could you please help me with this Upgrade scenario?

Regards,
Suyash Bhalekar